# imageview DrawingCache returns null

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

i'm using DrawingCache but it gives me NullPointerException

my code is as below:

```
    myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    myImageView.buildDrawingCache();
    resized = myImageView.getDrawingCache();        
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String save_location = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/EditedImage";
            File dir = new File(save_location);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            File f = new File(dir, TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

error is at onClick.

my logcat is 
[image]
what is missing in this?

Comment: Can you post your code or logcat ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this examle:**

```
myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

myImageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
myImageView.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), myImageView.getMeasuredHeight()); 

myImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);


Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImageView.getDrawingCache());
myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

Updated:

Another way, you can create a Canvas for the Bitmap and then call view.draw(canvas) like:

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
         Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height,              Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                


         Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
         v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
         v.draw(c);
         return b;
    }
```

Comment: Is hardware acceleration turned on? When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag.

Comment: i dont knw abt it.. hw to check that??

Answer (score 0):

Each view will take some procedure, for example, measure and layout, before it is drew on screen. So when you invoke getDrawingCache() in Activity.onCreate(), the view is not drew yet.

Put the following two lines in your onclick method.

```
myImageView.buildDrawingCache();
resized = myImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: I cannot believe it. Try to get the drawing cache in your click method, it cannot be null.

Comment: when i write jst above two line then it is not giving me error but it thorws error at resized.compress .... But to save that image i need to compress it..